# Yii2 checkbox default value is not being sent to the server

Tags: php, yii2

Here is my code :

```
$model->free = true;
echo $form->field($model, 'free', ['inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form-control input-lg ']])->checkbox();
```

What I want is if the user doesn't uncheck, the default value must be sent to the server but my surprise, it is sending $model->free to the server null whether the user unchecks or leaves it as it is; to send the checked value, the user has to uncheck and check which stress.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Add your model and controller.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `uncheck = false` works fine:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'free', ['inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form-control input-lg ']])->checkbox(['uncheck' => false]);
```

As Chinmay mentioned, more details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'free', ['inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form-control input-lg ']])->checkbox( [ 'uncheck' => 0 ] );
```

For more details refer to [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set value attribute `'value'=>'1'` to checkbox. Your code should be like.

**View File**

```
$isCheckedFree = true;
echo $form->field($model, 'free', ['inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form-control input-lg ']])->checkbox(['checked'=>$isCheckedFree,'value'=>'1']);
```

**Controller code**

```
if(isset($model->free) && $model->free=!null){
    $free = "Y"; // You can set your value
}else{
    $free = "N"; // You can set your value
}
```